# Como informar a maior sequência consecutiva?

Tags: java, array, lógica

Pessoal estou enganchado neste algoritmo onde eu crio um vetor inteiro com n posições e preciso mostrar a maior sequência consecutiva.

deixarei o enunciado para tentar ser mais específico.

"Elabore um algoritmo onde o usuário digite 50 números inteiros de um vetor e ao final o programa informa o tamanho da maior sequência consecutiva crescente."

ex:

6,7,9. MaiorSequência=2.

5,6,7,8,11. MaiorSequência=4

O que eu fiz até agora:

```
public class Questao02 {

        public static void main(String[] args){
            String aux;
            int a[] = new int[5];
            int cont=0;

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                aux = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Números");
                a[i] = Integer.parseInt(aux);

                if(a[i] < a[i+1] ){
                    cont++;

                }

                else{
                    cont=0;

                }

            }

            System.out.println(cont);
        }
}
```

Comment: Não é um algoritmo difícil mesmo para que está a começar. Vai ter de usar um `for` para percorrer o vetor e variáveis para contabilizar as sequencias encontradas e verificar se a sequência que tem até ao momento é maior que a que já apanhou até ali.

Comment: Quando eu utilizar o for pra percorrer o vetor eu preciso fazer uma comparação entre o valor atual que estar armazenado no vetor com o próximo valor do vetor né, eu tentei fazer isso aqui mas ta dando errado.

Comment: Se você não adicionar sua tentativa e colar apenas o enunciado, a pergunta será fechada novamente. Edite-a e demonstre o que já tentou fazer, demonstrando que teve algum esforço em tentar algo.

Comment: Articuno, irei adicionar o código que eu tentei fazer

Comment: E aproveite também para mostrar exatemente qual o ponto do código que não lhe está a funcionar e que está a criar dificuldades. Caso contrário é difícil a comunidade conseguir ajuda-lo a resolver o problema

Comment: E não esqueça de explicar em que ponto esta sua dificuldade, conforme foi dito pelo @Isac.

Comment: O meu problema é que não tô conseguindo enxergar uma solução no if, sei que ele ta errado e também eu tô com dificuldade em pegar o próximo valor do vetor, eu não sei se fazer a[i+1], está certo.

Comment: Ta mesclando interface grafica com modo de texto? Recomendo nao fazer isso, é uma pratica pessima.

Comment: Eu gosto de usar o Scanner, o JOption estou utilizando por curiosidade, além de não ser recomendado neste caso pelo fato dele aceitar apenas Strings, aí tive que fazer essa adaptação, usando a variável aux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É importante separar a introdução dos valores, da lógica de contabilização. Neste caso até simplifica pois a contabilização não pode ser feita para todos os valores porque considera o valor da frente, logo tem de terminar um antes do fim.

Precisa também de outra variável para guardar a sequencia máxima encontrada até ao momento, caso contrário quando o `cont` volta a `0` perde a sequencia anterior que podia até ser maior.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[] = new int[5];
    int cont = 0;
    int maior = 0; //nova variável para a maior sequencia achada

    //só a leitura
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        //sem aux para simplificar
        a[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Números"));
    }

    //só a contabilização
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){ //até ao 4, um antes do fim
        if(a[i] == a[i+1]-1){ //teste de valor 1 abaixo, em vez de apenas inferior
            cont++;

            //verifica e atualiza com a maior sequência
            if (cont > maior){  achada até ao momento
                maior = cont;
            }
        }
        else{
            cont=0;
        }
    }

    //quando testa se o número é sequencia com o da frente o maior vai ficar com 1 mas
    //a sequência já representa dois números, logo é necessário no fim somar 1
    maior++;
    System.out.println(maior);
}
```

Considerações:

- Assim como o Articuno disso não é boa ideia misturar interface gráfica e modo consola, por isso considere usar `Scanner` e `nextInt()` para leitura, por consistência.
- Da forma que está o `parseInt` pode lançar exceção se o utilizador não introduzir um número. Considere por isso utilizar tratamento de exceções com `try` `catch` se quiser evitar que o programa rebente nesse caso.

Comment: Obrigado, realmente eu não tinha pensado em criar outro for para contabilizar e usar os if dessa maneira. o código ficou bem educativo aprendi bastante, com certeza irá servir de experiência. Eu tava usando o JOption por curiosidade, já que o professor mostrou em sala de aula, mas como vocês falaram que não é uma pratica muito legal, vou ficar utilizando o Scanner.